# Displaying specific row from INNER JOIN - mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli, inner-join, backend

I am trying to display information about currently logged in user. The problem is information I need are in two differnet tables so I had to use INNER JOIN and I have problem to display data.

```
<?php 
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$sql_address = 
"SELECT `customer`.`email`, `address`.`first_name`, `address`.`last_name` 
FROM `customer` INNER JOIN address ON `customer`.`customer_ID`=`address`.`customer_ID WHERE email =". $email; 
$result_address = $db->query($sql_address);


if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_address)){ ?>
                         <div class="col-sm-4 mb-20">
                            <div class="mb-20 mb-md-10">
                               <h3> CUSTOMER DETAILS</h3>
                               <p>Name: <?php echo $row['first_name']. " " .$row['last_name'];?><br/>
                                  Email: <?php echo $row['email'];?>
                               </p>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <?php }?>
```

At this moment I am getting this error :

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xamp\htdocs\exercises\website\shipment.php on line 149
```

Can you please tell me where is a problem? Also do you have any suggestion how to make it more secure? I guess putting `$email` into `query` is probably not the best idea.

Comment: change `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_address)){` to `while($row = $result_address->fetch_array()){` also wrap/quote your where condition `WHERE email =". $email;` to `WHERE email ='". $email."'"; `

Comment: Have you used `mysqli_query` function??

Comment: have a look for basic use of mysqli https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage

Comment: @Patricia You missed a backtick here `customer_ID\' WHERE email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably You have an error in sql statement, so $result_address is false. $email should be in single quotes, and also add close quote to the `customer_ID

Try this query

```
SELECT `customer`.`email`, `address`.`first_name`, `address`.`last_name` 
FROM `customer` INNER JOIN address ON `customer`.`customer_ID`=`address`.`customer_ID` WHERE email = '". $email . "'";
```